# Calling async handler method causes: Socket must be bound to a local endpoint to perform this operation

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, network-programming, windows-phone

I created server where I wait for data. When I call `AcceptAsync` the handling method  `connectArgs_Accepted` is called and that causes exceptions and crash even when method is empty iniside. How to deal with that?

```
   Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(connect));
        thread.Start();
    }

    Socket connection;
    SocketAsyncEventArgs connectArgs;
    string ip = "192.168.0.13";
    int port = 13001;
    private void connect() {
        connectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(ip, port) };

        connectArgs.Completed += connectArgs_Accepted;
        connection = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                  connection.AcceptAsync(connectArgs);
    }

    void connectArgs_Accepted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {//that causes exception
     /*   if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
            // data sent
            try {

                Receive();

            } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
        } else {
            // error
        }*/
    }
```

Output:

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: Socket must be bound to a local endpoint to perform this operation.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at HomeSecurityClient.JPGServer.connect()
The thread 0x458 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

.
The Client side(sender)

```
namespace HomeSecurity {
    //singleton
    public class JPGClient {
        IPAddress ip;
        int port;
        public static JPGClient JPG_CLIENT = null;

        public JPGClient(IPAddress ip, int port) {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port + 1;
            JPG_CLIENT = this;

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendjpg));
            thread.Start();

        }
        public void sendjpg() {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            try {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ip  + " X " + 13001);
                client.Connect(ip, 13001);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ip + " polaczzyl X " + 13001);


                // Retrieve the network stream.  
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
                imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\a.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                MessageData data = new MessageData(imageBrush);

                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                while (true) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
                    formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    // data.GetNewImage();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Server sockets (that accept client connections) should be bound to the local network interface and port first.
Before calling AcceptAsync you should bind socket to the local endpoint.

Have a look at [Socket.Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) info (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind(v=vs.110).aspx)